# An Example of a non-diagonalizable $4 \times 4$ skew-symmetric matrix with non-zero eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I looked around this site to see if there is any question that addresses my concern, but so far, I couldn't find any. I apologize that if this ends up being a duplicate, but I have been looking for a while. I am having much difficulties in concocting an example of a $4 \times 4$ skew-symmetric matrix with entries in $\mathbb{C}$ that is not-diagonalizable with non-zero eigenvalues. I have tried using Wolfram-Alpha (Jordan Normal Form Calculator Online), inputting different values to make different skew symmetric matrices, but the matrix I end up concocting ends up being diagonalizable.

First of all, I was reading the following paper:

> Olga Ruff, *[The Jordan Canonical Forms of complex orthogonal and skew-symmetric matrices: characterization and examples](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/dept/thesisarchive/MSCC/RuffMSSS07.pdf)*, Master thesis, Iowa State University, 2007.

The fact that there are nondiagonalizable skew symmetric matrices is mentioned on page 35 under Lemma 5.2.1.

As far as I know, if this fact is true, can someone provide me a simple example. If not, maybe a link or theorem that states such scenario is not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: i am not sure but seems that every endomorphism with entries in $\mathbb{C}$ is diagonalizable, since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed

Comment: @haemhweg Thanks for the comment. Maybe if I can recall some result in Linear Algebra that states that, I am set. I'm starting to believe that there is no such example, but I could be wrong.

Comment: here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Examples

Comment: When we talk about skew-symmetric matrices with complex entries, by definition it is transposing and conjugating the entries, right? NOT the condition $A = -A^T$.

Comment: Actually as i know matrix you've mentioned is Hermitian matrix (also called conjugate transpose). Take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix. And skew-symmetric matrix is a matrix s.t. $A=-A^T$

Comment: @haemhweg Ah I see, thanks. So I do not see anything in the first link mentioning about whether skew-symmetric matrices (with complex entries) are diagonalizable or not (for $4 \times 4$ matrices). I believe there's a theorem that state that every matrix can be written as a direct sum of symmetric and skew symmetric matrices. So from this, it seems such an example is possible.

Comment: Every skew-Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable, so you would be looking for a complex matrix such that $A = -A^\top$ and *not* the conjugate with the transpose, since that would make it skew-Hermitian. Sorry that I can not give an example right now. Note that if you use only real entries, then it will be again diagonalizable.

Comment: @Food4Thought: Have you considered following that logic? Start with a non-diagonalisable matrix, then find the skew-symmetric part of it? Haven't tried it myself, but it seems like it could be a useful approach.

Comment: @GlenO Yes. The issue I ran into was finding the right invertible matrix $g$ such that $gJg^{-1}$ equals a skew-symmetric matrix, where $J$ is the Jordan normal form (which consists of two jordan blocks, each block being a $2 \times 2$ with eigenvalues $\lambda, -\lambda$ for $\lambda \neq 0$).

Comment: @Food4Thought: I think you misunderstood. I'm saying, start with a **general** non-diagonalisable matrix (not skew-symmetric), then find the skew-symmetric part, and see if it's diagonalisable. Even if it is, it might give you an idea towards how to do it. As I said, it's just an idea, I don't know if it'll work.

Comment: @GlenO I'm uncertain what you mean by finding skew-symmetric part. Do elaborate. Are you saying decompose the non-diagonalizable matrix in terms of symmetric and skew-symmetric. If not, please do clarify as I have no clue what you mean by that.

Comment: @Food4Thought: Yes, exactly - decompose the non-diagonalisable matrix into its symmetric and skew-symmetric parts. The symmetric part has to be diagonalisable, so if there's a "cause" for nondiagonalisability (and I know it's not necessarily true that there has to be one), I'd expect it to come from the skew-symmetric part.

Comment: For the $2 \times 2$ case we have the complex skew-symmetric of the form
$$\pmatrix{0 & re^{i\theta} \\ -re^{i\theta} & 0} = e^{i\theta}\pmatrix{0 & r \\ -r & 0}$$
which can be seen to be a complex scalar of a real skew-symmetric matrix, and thus is going to be diagonalizable. This shows only that such an example does not exist for a $2\times 2$ matrix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the thesis carefully, you will see that it has already offered a way to constuct the desired skew symmetric matrix. For instance, the Jordan form $J=J_2(1)\oplus J_2(-1)$ -- which is not diagonalisable -- is similar to the skew symmetric matrix
$$
Y = \pmatrix{
0       &\frac12+i &0     &\frac{i}2\\
-\frac12-i  &0     &-\frac{i}2  &0\\
0       &\frac{i}2   &0     &-\frac12+i\\
-\frac{i}2    &0     &\frac12-i &0
}.
$$
You may [verify](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan%20decomposition%20%7B%7B0,1/2%2bi,0,i/2%7D,%7B-1/2-i,0,-i/2,0%7D,%7B0,i/2,0,-1/2%2bi%7D,%7B-i/2,0,1/2-i,0%7D%7D) that the Jordan form of $Y$ is indeed $J_2(1)\oplus J_2(-1)$.

---

Here are the details of construction. First of all, $J_2(1)\oplus J_2(-1)$ is similar to $\widetilde{J}=J_2(1)\oplus-J_2(1)$:
$$
\underbrace{\pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&1\\ &&&-1}}_{D}
\pmatrix{1&1\\ &1\\ &&-1&1\\ &&&-1}
\underbrace{\pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&1\\ &&&-1}}_{D^{-1}}
=\pmatrix{1&1\\ &1\\ &&-1&-1\\ &&&-1}.
$$
Yet $J_2(1)$ is similar to a complex symmetric matrix (theorem 2.1.4):
$$
\underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&i\\ i&1}}_{B}
\ \pmatrix{1&1\\ &1}
\ \underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&-i\\ -i&1}}_{B^{-1}}
=\underbrace{\pmatrix{1-\frac{i}{2}&\frac12\\ \frac12&1+\frac{i}{2}}}_{S}.
$$
Therefore $\widetilde{J}$ is similar to $A=S\oplus -S$.

Let $H=\pmatrix{0&I_2\\ I_2&0}$. Then $HAH^{-1}=-A$. We have $H=X^TX$, where
$$
X=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{
i &0 &-i &0\\
1 &0 &1  &0\\
0 &i &0  &-i\\
0 &1 &0  &1}.
$$
Therefore, by the proof of lemma 5.1.2 and by lemma 5.2.1, $Y = XAX^{-1}$ is skew symmetric.

Putting all the pieces together, we have $Y=PJP^{-1}$, where
$$
P = X(B\oplus B)D = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{
 i &-1 &-i &-1\\
 1 & i & 1 &-i\\
-1 & i & 1 & i\\
 i & 1 & i &-1}.
$$