# If $n$ is even, every skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can be factored as $A=SBS^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $n$ is even, every skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can be factored as $A=SBS^T$ where $S$ is a invertible matrix and $B$ has the form $B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a_1 & 0 & 0 &0&0\\
-a_1 & 0 &0&0 &0&0\\
0&0&0&a_{2}&0&0\\
0 & 0&-a_{2}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&a_{n/2}\\
0&0&0&0&-a_{n/2}&0 \end{array} \right)$

The $a_{n/2}$ is supposed to represent that $B$ can be any even $n\times n$ size (the size of $A$).

So my book shows this result without proving it, and I was wondering why it's true. It doesn't seem clear to me why this specific factorization holds. How can you prove that it's true? What would $S$ or $S^T$ look like?

Some useful results:

> If $E$ is an elementary matrix obtained from $I_n$ by carrying out one
>   elementary row operation on $I_n$, then $EA$ is a matrix obtained by
>   carrying out a single elementary row operation on $A$, and $AE$ is a
>   matrix obtained by carrying out a single elementary column operation
>   on $A$.
>
> $A$ is invertible iff it can be factored as a product of elementary
>   matrices: $A = E_1...E_m$.

Comment: Hint: The eigenvalues of $A$ are all imaginary, and come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Is $S$ supposed to be orthogonal?

Comment: @darijgrinberg it says $S$ is invertible, but does not specify it has to be orthogonal.

Comment: I cannot really comment on the general case, but Travis's comment seems to refer to the case when $A$ has real entries -- I suspect that the book you are talking about is tacitly assuming so. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370272/an-example-of-a-non-diagonalizable-4-times-4-skew-symmetric-matrix-with-non-z .

Comment: Oh, I see. Nice problem, and holds over every field of characteristic $\neq 2$. In basis-free terms, it asks you to show that, given a skew-symmetric form $B$ on an even-dimensional vector space $V$, you can find a basis $\left(e_1,f_1,e_2,f_2,...,e_n,f_n\right)$ of $V$ such that $B\left(e_i,f_j\right) = \delta_{i,j}$, $B\left(f_i,e_j\right) = -\delta_{i,j}$, $B\left(e_i,e_j\right) = 0$, and $B\left(f_i,f_j\right) = 0$ for all $i$ and $j$. (Here the form is $\left(x,y\right) \mapsto x^TAy$, and the basis will make the columns of $\left(S^T\right)^{-1}$.) This can be done by induction.

Comment: Actually, this exercise in its basis-free form is rather well-known. When $B$ is nondegenerate, $B$ is called a symplectic form, and the basis we are seeking is known as a symplectic basis; a proof of its existence can be found, e.g., in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf Theorem 5.4. In the general case, proceed the same way, picking a nonsingular vector at every step until no more nonsingular vectors can be found.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm honestly unfamiliar with many of the concepts you're speaking about here. Is there a relatively "simple" way to show that $A$ can be factored into $SBS^T$?

Comment: Sorry, not under my current time constraints :( Keith Conrad's note should be very illuminating, however.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm still having a very hard time with this, if you can take a look at my additional information provided.